# Apply function javascript looping extra

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to Javascript and created a sample function to test the apply function of the javascript.

I need couple of clarification on this code,

1. value -x will take the first array ['val1','val2'] but just wondering it substitutes to (this,x)..
   2.I see a 3 items being printed in the console.log, the last item being - undefined, undefined, What that happends

   ```
   var dummyfunction1 = function(val1,val2){
       console.log(array1,array2);
   };

   [['val1','val2'],['val3','val4']].forEach(function(x){
       dummyfunction1.apply(this,x);
   });

   dummyfunction1()
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

dummyfunction1 is using variable that are undefined in the body. It should be this:

```
var dummyfunction1 = function(val1,val2){
    console.log(val1,val2);
};
```

The last line `dummyfunction1()` is making an additional call to the dummyfunction1 with no parameters. This is the undefined undefined you are seeing.

The full code should be this:

```
var dummyfunction1 = function(val1,val2){
    console.log(val1,val2);
};

// this will automatically be run, no need to call dummyfunction1 on your own after this
[['val1','val2'],['val3','val4']].forEach(function(x){
    dummyfunction1.apply(this,x);
});
```